# Microsost Office Interop Word - enable/disable track changes in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

How do I enable or disable Track Changes option in C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for this property

[Document.TrackRevisions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.trackrevisions)

as from MSDN

> This property returns True if changes are tracked in the specified document, 
>      and False if they are not. Set the property value to True or False to enable or 
>      disable the functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Set

```
wordDocument.TrackRevisions = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable  Track Changes :

```
wordDocument.TrackRevisions = true;
```

Disable Track Changes :

```
wordDocument.TrackRevisions = false;
```